# Tangent space at function of torus and circle

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the torus
>
> $S^1 \times S^1 := [(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in E^4 \space  | \space x_1^2+x_2^2=1,\space x_3^2+x_4^2=1]$.
>
> And the sphere
>
> $S^2 := [(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in E^4 \space  | \space x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1]$.
>
> Let $f: S^1 \times S^1 \to S^2$ be the smooth map such that
>
> $f(z,w) = \left( \space[\bar{z},\bar{w}]\sigma_1 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
> z \\ w \end{array} \right], [\bar{z},\bar{w}]\sigma_2 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
> z \\ w \end{array} \right], [\bar{z},\bar{w}]\sigma_3 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
> z \\ w \end{array} \right]\right)$
>
> Here $z=x_1+ix_2, w=x_3+ix_4$, and $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices:
>
> $\sigma_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right], \sigma_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array} \right], \sigma_3 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]$
>
> **Question:** Compute $T_pf$ for any point p in the torus. Is $T_pf$ always a linear equivalence?

I just know that if given that $f(p)=q$ ,

$T_pf: T_p S^1 \times S^1 \to T_qS^2, \quad  (p,\underline{u}) \mapsto (q, f_\underline{u}(p))$.

But following that I have no idea. Can anyone help?